# Integration by Substitution of a fraction with the numerator having a square root

Tags: calculus, integration

I can't seem to see how to split or simplify this before integrating:

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{3x+5}}{x} \, dx$$. Any ideas where to start from?...using integration by substitution that is

Comment: Try to multiply the top and bottom by the numerator, then split apart the fraction (using partial fractions) and let tangent substitution do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Using the change of variables $3x+5=u^2$ gives

> $$ 2\,\int \!{\frac {{u}^{2}}{{u}^{2}-5}}{du}. $$

Now, I am sure you can finish it.

Comment: As a general comment, integration by substitution is analogous to the chain rule ("function of a function") in differentiation. So when you see one function nested inside another (here $3x+5$ is nested inside the square root) that's often a good thing to substitute for. Since it's inside a square root, making it $u^2$ rather than $u$ looks like it might make life easier: that way you get rid of the square root, which is one of the things that looked hard in the question. Aiming for the "function inside a function" doesn't _always_ work, but if you're not sure where to start, is worth a try!

Comment: This doesn't quite work as listed.  $3\mathrm{d}x = 2u\mathrm{d}u$ and $|u|=\sqrt{3x+5}$.  Basically, the $u^2$ on the numerator shouldn't be there, and one should perhaps be careful on whether both sign choices for $u$ are meaningful to the original integral or not.

Comment: @Silverfish,@zibadawa: I do not think the problem needs all of these detailed comments!! By the way, you can use the substitution $\sqrt{3x+5}=u$ if this makes you happy.

Comment: @Downvoter: What's the down vote for?

Comment: @Mhenni my comment was aimed at the OP, but as it referred to your answer I thought it belonged here rather than attached to the original question. In short the OP had "no idea where to start from" - in such a situation it can be helpful to motivate "why" a particular substitution is picked. No idea what the downvote was for, I thought this was a perfectly neat answer for a question of this level.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: The substituion works fine, as $x>0$, $u>\sqrt{5}$, there is no need for a sign change.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: Your substitution works fine... Voteup!